# Is it possible to make an Iphone app with 0 experience?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to start building apps starting off with a small one. Is this even possible or d I have to learn code from going to school or get training?

Comment: This all depends on how motivated you are / how talented you are. Why not just give it a try (lots of tutorials or books are available). Objective-C isn't the most forgiving beginner's language though...

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  It's also possible for me to give you open-heart surgery.  But since I'm not a surgeon, the results would not be good.  The same principle applies here.  Learn some easier programming languages first and tool around with them for a while until you're comfortable enough to learn something more complex, like Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming an iPhone App has nothing to do with rocket science at all, but there are some drawbacks to it:

- You will have to use Objective-C as a programming language, which has quite a steep learning curve.
- Albeit a lot of books being around on the topic of iPhone/iOS programming, I still have to see one written particularly for people new to programming in general. Same goes for the tutorials. Once you've written your first classic "Hello, world" programme, things will start to become difficult.
- XCode (the development environment most people use) has a lot of stuff going on, which might seem to be a bit obscure at first sight (things like plist and their usage, the whole Interface Builder thing etc. come to mind).

As ChristopheD mentioned: Objective-C isn't one of the most forgiving programming languages at all (pure C isn't either, so why should its superset be?) and I can entirely second cdhowies advice to learn a more beginner friendly programming language (Java, for instance) first.

Whatever your decision will be: welcome to a really fascinating world!

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible, as others have noted, It will indeed take a *lot* of determination and effort.

Programming is a learnable skill like most others, but like any skill that pays well, it's not something you pick up over a weekend, or a week, or month. To create your first iPhone app of any real complexity if you've not programmed before -- and even simple apps are usually much more complex behind the scenes than they seem -- it's going to take months at least.

I encourage you to go for it, though, if you're willing to put in the effort. Start by learning to program in general; if you start with Objective-C and Cocoa Touch and the Xcode IDE (integrated development environment), it's likely to be overwhelming. **Head First Programming** is quite good, my girlfriend learned the basics of programming with it in just a few months of spare time, and it was clear from her questions that she really was learning the essential concepts. You'll be learning Python, which isn't like C or Objective-C in syntax or structure, but 95%+ of what you learn will transfer.

Next I suggest plowing into Objective-C. There are several good books out there; the one that I particularly liked escapes my mind at the moment, but some Amazon reviews will be able to guide you to a good choice. While learning the language there will likely be a few concepts you're missing that will require further investigation on your part, some object-oriented programming basics for instance, but you can likely fill the gap with some online resources.

After that go for iPhone programming with a book like **Head First iPhone Programming** (I have nothing o do with either book, btw); I've seen two people learn from it quite successfully. With most of that book under your belt you'll be able to write a variety of basic apps.

Importantly, with the experience of three books along those lines you'll be at a point where you'll be able to ask questions here at Stack Overflow in a clear enough manner that you'll get useful answers. If you start asking iPhone programming questions right away, odds are you won't be asking something that can really be answered, and even if so, the answers won't necessarily make sense to you.

Like I said at the start, it will likely be months before you're able to build something you're satisfied with, and it could be many months if you can only do it in your spare time, but it's definitely doable.

Lastly, understand that a crash course like this won't make you a *good* programmer, and won't give you the skills to write complex apps: only experience can do that. Keep programming, read online tutorials and blogs, and answer questions here on SO that you're qualified for (something that teaches you a lot, btw). Within a few years you may well qualify as good, and be on your way to great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and you do not have to go to school.
Programming is not for genius people.

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Go for it.